# Issue with spaces in path name in Excel macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, path

VLOOKUP definition is:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'[\\sqlc\Curr table & Checklist\Currency table - foreign.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R9999C2,2,FALSE))=FALSE,VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'[\\sqlc\Curr table & Checklist\Currency table - foreign.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R9999C2,2,FALSE),""No a/c"")
```

Excel is throwing an error due to the space between 'Curr' and 'table' in the path name (and would also get upset about the following spaces in the path name as well).

Q: Where do I insert speech marks (") to overcome the problem.  Have tried several options but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put quotes (") around the entire path.

In this case, your code should look like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'["\sqlc\Curr table & Checklist\Currency table - foreign.xlsx"]Sheet1'!R2C1:R9999C2,2,FALSE))=FALSE,VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'[\sqlc\Curr table & Checklist\Currency table - foreign.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R9999C2,2,FALSE),""No a/c"")
```